# Meteor call resulting in Collection.insert: how to make this run synchronously?

Tags: meteor

I know how to make Meteor methods run synchronously via either the `Meteor.wrapAsynch` and creating `new future()` on the server.

However, I'm having this problem when I call on a method via `Meteor.call("myMethod")` to insert or delete a document. A `Collection.insert` is supposed to by synchronous by nature, but on my application, it seems to run asynchronously because there are times when the entire document doesn't fully insert into the DB before iron router takes me to the next page.

Here is how my code looks on client (took most of it out because it's irrelevant):

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  "submit .legitForm": function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

    Meteor.call("deleteData");
    });

// Do file manipulation in this space.

      async.each(array, processingFxn, function(error) {

        flattened = _.flatten(results);

        Meteor.call("insertCollect", flattened);
      });
```

On server, the methods are the generic Collection.insert and remove:

```
  Meteor.methods({
    insertColl: function(document){
      var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
      Bank.insert({userId: currentUser, data: document});

    },
    deleteData: function(){
      Bank.remove({userId: this.userId});
    }
  });
```

Ideally I want the first delete call to finish before going on to the file manipulation part, etc, etc. I tried passing callbacks in the Collection.insert and remove methods, but it doesn't work because I guess that turns the insert and remove methods asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Meteor docs says if a callback is provided it is used, otherwise the method is called synchronously 'if possible'.

To insure order you should use a callback there:

```
    Template.myTemplate.events({
      "submit .legitForm": function(e){
         e.preventDefault();

        Meteor.call("deleteData", function(result) {
          // Do file manipulation in this space.
          async.each(array, processingFxn, function(error) {
            flattened = _.flatten(results);
            Meteor.call("insertCollect", flattened);
        });
    });
});
```